# Next-Auth expires session and shows signIn error

Tags: typescript, next.js13, next-auth

I let the browser open for 2 hours and when I came back it showed the following:
[Link to my browser screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcwRS.png)

Our JWT expires in a month. I don't know if Next-Auth has some automatic expiration time when inactive, but this is annoying me. I don't know if i need to add some extra settings in the options.ts to specify the expire time of the JWT. This is my options.ts:

```js
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2h54xz6Ndw&t=1721s

import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import AppleProvider from "next-auth/providers/apple"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';

import axios from 'axios';
import loginService from "../../../../services/login";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
        AppleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.APPLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.APPLE_SECRET as string,
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "Email"
                },
                username: {
                    label: "Username",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "Username"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password:",
                    type: "password",
                    placeholder: "Password"
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // This is where you need to retrieve user data 
                // to verify with credentials
                // Docs: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials
                let loginObject = {};
                if (credentials?.username) {
                    loginObject = {
                        username: credentials?.username,
                        password: credentials?.password
                    }
                } else if (credentials?.email) {
                    loginObject = {
                        email: credentials?.email,
                        password: credentials?.password
                    }
                }

                let user = await loginService.login(loginObject);

                // modify object
                user = {
                    id: user.data_user.id,
                    username: user.data_user.username,
                    email: user.data_user.email,
                    general_folder_id: user.data_user.folder_id,
                    token: user.token
                }


                if (user.username && user.email) {
                    console.log(user)
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            return { ...token, ...user };
        },

        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token as any;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
        // error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
        // verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request', // (used for check email message)
        // newUser: '/auth/new-user' // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
    }
};
```